# Properly pushing a Canvas with Material UI Persistent Drawers

Tags: css, reactjs, html5-canvas, material-ui

I have an application with two expandable toolbars. The left toolbar functions as intended, but I have not been able to make the right toolbar push the content properly. See the code below.

I copied the exact code from here - see Persistent Drawers: https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/

The KeyboardListener is display:none and the SceneCanvas element has the following styling:

```
root: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 0,
    lineHeight: 0,
    cursor: 'crosshair',
}
```

The desired functionality is for both the left and right toolbars to push the content in and resize the canvas and the canvas content. And tips or insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import SceneCanvas from '../../three/SceneCanvas';
import KeyboardListener from '../KeyboardListener';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  appFrame: {
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  'appBarShift-left': {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
  },
  'appBarShift-right': {
    marginRight: drawerWidth,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  'content-left': {
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
  },
  'content-right': {
    marginRight: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  'contentShift-left': {
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
  'contentShift-right': {
    marginRight: 0,
  },
});

class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    anchor: 'left',
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleChangeAnchor = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      anchor: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    const { anchor, open } = this.state;

    const drawer = (
      <Drawer
        variant="persistent"
        anchor={anchor}
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>Testing</List>
        <Divider />
        <List>Testing</List>
      </Drawer>
    );

    let before = null;
    let after = null;

    if (anchor === 'left') {
      before = drawer;
    } else {
      after = drawer;
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <TextField
          id="persistent-anchor"
          select
          label="Anchor"
          value={anchor}
          onChange={this.handleChangeAnchor}
          margin="normal"
        >
          <MenuItem value="left">left</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="right">right</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
              [classes.appBarShift]: open,
              [classes[`appBarShift-${anchor}`]]: open,
            })}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                className={classNames(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Persistent drawer
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          {before}
          <main
            className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-${anchor}`], {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
              [classes[`contentShift-${anchor}`]]: open,
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            <KeyboardListener />
            <SceneCanvas />
          </main>
          {after}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Header);
```

Left Toolbar Functioning Properly

[image]

Right Toolbar Breaking

[image]

Desired Function
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any way you can get this snippet to run somewhere? Or are you open to a css only example?

Comment: @SergChernata This was just the easiest way to show the problem. We found a solution but it wasn't related to the code above. I'll see if we can post the solution here.

Comment: I guess the problem is due to negative margins? Maybe you should set the correct width of the canvas instead of setting negative margins?

Comment: You may be able to use padding to offset the negative margins? That's what it sounds like when using the Grid component (which also uses negative margins)